# What is this math symbol and how do I replicate it?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I’m reading an article and this symbol appeared:

[image]

What is the latex command for this?

Comment: This looks like a calligraphic T.

Comment: This is a fraktur T. When loading `amssymb` you can get it with `\mathfrak{T}`. For next time, a great tool to find symbols is [detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).